# Reset Ini files button delphi

Tags: delphi, ini, delete-file

I want to create a reset button for my delphi program. In my program sometimes there are some Ini. files created in the pathexe. What I want to do is now create a button or a tab that lets me click on it and when it does. It deletes all the .Ini files in my pathexe

How could I do this?

Also I want to know how to make a little 'Are you sure?' pop up, but that's a minor detail.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to store the settings INI file in the same directory as the EXE file. Indeed, the EXE file most likely resides in the Program Files folder, and this is read-only unless you are running the program as an administrator, and normally you aren't. Instead, you should use the per-user app data folder, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219255/why-do-files-get-placed-c-users-usernameappdata-local-virtualstore-program-fil/3219276#3219276).

Comment: Unless ini settings are common across all users (I use an ini file to maintain dynamic performance related settings), in which case you neeed to store it in the all-users app data folder and give this particular folder (a sub-folder off all users) write-rights for everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code below uses uses wildcard to get list of ini files and delete one by one.

```
procedure DeleteIni();
var searchResult : TSearchRec;
begin
  if FindFirst('*.ini', faAnyFile, searchResult) = 0 then
  begin
    repeat
      DeleteFile(searchResult.Name);
    until FindNext(searchResult) <> 0;
    FindClose(searchResult);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 6):

You should do something like

```
  if MessageBox(Handle, 'Are you sure you want to restore the default settings?',
    PChar(Caption), MB_ICONQUESTION or MB_YESNO) = ID_YES then
  begin
    DeleteFile(SettingsFileName);
    LoadSettings;
  end;
```

where `SettingsFileName` is the file name of the INI file (which resides in a [per-user location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219255/why-do-files-get-placed-c-users-usernameappdata-local-virtualstore-program-fil/3219276#3219276)), and `LoadSettings` is the procedure that you use to load the settings from the INI file (which, of course (!), applies the default settings should there be no INI file).