# Where does tmpfile() store the files it creates (in mingw-gcc/windows 7)?

Tags: c, windows-7, mingw, temporary-files

I'm testing tmpfile() with mingw-gcc (CodeBlocks, latest) and program works as expected: opens 10 temp files, write 10 random strings, then read-back those 10 strings and close each *fp.

Like I said, works as expected but reading some articles about temporarily locations on win7, I begun to search where actually the files are stored, before auto-erase. On UNIX, the default location would be /tmp

On windows 7, I'm running out of ideas...
- the program folder
- the user/appdata/local/tmp/
- windows/temp

I cannot find those files and I searched even with total commander from some known strings inside. None. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same question, and after reviewing the thread linked here:

http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/666/

... I think the MinGW guys rolled a special version that keeps the temporary file *entirely in memory*.

I don't know how complete their solution is without combing through MinGW's source and/or asking on the mailing lists. In either case, it is probably a better idea to use some function other than tmpfile() anyway, given its problems.

Answer (score 0):

I used Process Explorer to monitor the open handles on this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("%p", tmpfile());
    scanf("%d", &a);
    return 0;
}
```

After `printf("%p", tmpfile());` was executed, a new file handle was opened, and the file path was `C:\Users\sashoalm\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\t9mc`. I ran the program again and this time it was `C:\Users\sashoalm\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\t728`. So it places them in `C:\Users\sashoalm\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\`, and the name is some randomly generated string starting with "t".

See [Why do files get placed in "C:\Users\<username>AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files(x86)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219255/why-do-files-get-placed-in-c-users-usernameappdata-local-virtualstore-progra) about the "Virtual Store" folder.

Answer (score -1):

/ I tested Dev-C++ 5.11 (Mngv) gcc, and dont work. With Borland 5.5 in Code:: Block no problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char filename[L_tmpnam];
    char *strs[] = {"Hello\n","Goodbye\n","Cat\n","Dog\n",NULL};
    char **mover = strs;
    char line[80],command[80];
    FILE *fp;

    fp = tmpfile();
    for(; *mover != NULL; mover++) fputs(*mover,fp);
    rewind(fp);
    while(fgets(line,80,fp))printf("%s",line);
    fclose(fp);

    if(tmpnam(filename) == NULL){
        printf("Could not get non-conflicting file name\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("\nFilename obtained is: %s\n\n",filename);
    fp = fopen(filename, "w+");
    for(mover = strs; *mover != NULL; mover++) fputs(*mover, fp);
    rewind(fp);
    while(fgets(line,80,fp)) printf("%s",line);
    putchar('\n');
    fclose(fp);


    return 0;
}
```