# XmlDocument Save In other places

Tags: c#, xml

```
XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
XmlDeclaration xmldecl = xd.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
xd.AppendChild(xmldecl);             
XmlElement xe = xd.CreateElement("root");
xd.AppendChild(xe);
xd.Save(@"C:\Windows\Config.xml");
```

I want to create an XML file in this director, but in fact it saves it in this place

> C:\Users\wjl\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Windows

Comment: The parameter for the `.Save` will be the file path to save to.. whats not working?

Comment: You probably don't have write access to the `C:\Windows` directory. Are you running the program on elevated-mode?

Comment: The windows directory is a protected directory. It seems like your mindset is stuck in the 90s :) There should be no reason whatsoever for you to write *anything* in there!

Comment: This is related to the issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219255/why-do-files-get-placed-in-c-users-usernameappdata-local-virtualstore-progra). As pointed out by the other commenters, C:\Windows is a protected directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of Windows UAC, when you don't have permission to write in the Windows folder it is written in your VirtualStore instead.

Run your application as administrator an it should write to the real windows folder instead.

You can read more about UAC virtualization on [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.06.uac.aspx).