# InnoSetup - Creating files at App Directory and not at AppData

Tags: ruby, windows, installation, inno-setup

My application is a "self-contained" ruby app.
It downloads images from the web.

When I run it, the files are created at the root app folder.

I created a InnoSetup installer. Installer works as expected, installing at `Program Files`. When I run the app, it creates files at `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\MyApp` instead of the root app data.

How can I keep creating the files at my app folder, instead of `AppData`? Why does this occur? Couldn't find any info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do files get placed in "C:\Users\<username>AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files(x86)"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219255/why-do-files-get-placed-in-c-users-usernameappdata-local-virtualstore-progra)

Comment: See also http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66275/Windows-Vista-File-and-Registry-Virtualization for background

Comment: In short: if you don't want to change your application, you either have to run it with admin privileges or don't install it under programming files but in a separate directory c:\myapp for example

Comment: @NineBerry got it. But if I just copy my app to program files, and run it, the files are created with no problem inside the `Program Files` folder... How can this be possible?

Comment: @RafaelOliveira It's not possible. Unless you run the application with admin privileges. How do you check that the files are created in the `Program Files` folder?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl looking inside the `Program Files/MyApp`. The files are just being downloaded there... I just copied my app to this folder and ran it as a regular user... Can't understand what is happening...

Comment: Sure, but how are you looking inside the `Program Files/MyApp`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I'm checking with Windows Explorer

Comment: And how do you copy the app to Program Files?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl via explorer as well...

Comment: So the Explorer prompts you for Admin credentials/privileges elevation for the copy, right?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl no, that's the strange thing... I just copy it and that's fine. Maybe my account has admin privileges, but if so when I used Inno Setup it shouldn't change the behavior...

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? Windows Explorer prompts you even if your account has administrator privileges. Unless you have disabled UAC in control panel, have you?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl no. I just installed Win7 on a VM (VirtualBox), no prompts at all...